# Run upgrade in is cmd not working wixsharp

Tags: wix, wixsharp

I implemented the `MajorUpgrade` element,

when I want to run the upgrade via the command line,

I have to to run the msi of the higher version with `/i` .(e.g `msiexec /i <path_to_higher_msi>`)

`/u` does nothing. (e.g does show no error/ no message at the event viewer and not install/upgrade)

How can I have it work?

For example:

I build the project with version `1.2.3` and install it.
Then I rebuild the same solution but with higher version `2.4.5`.
and run `msiexec /u`
I can see in the Control Panel that the version was updated.

The bug starts as I produces two releases from the pipeline..

I have the same `upgradeCode` in both and a unique `productId`
Tnx.

Comment: You can't install the same version. A major UPGRADE requires a higher version. "The same GUID" doesn't say anything. Do you mean product code or upgrade code?

Comment: @harper - I don't Install the same version, I added an example in the question. Can you have a look?

Comment: I didn't specify ProductId or upgradeCode. From what I read in the WixSharp documentation it's a combination of both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,
So I found the answer thanks to *wix-user-list*

There is no `/u` for upgrading,

`/u` is used for a patch in the current version, not for updating for an higher version